# How to split a file lines with space and tab differentiation?

Tags: c++, string, split, tabs, whitespace

I have a file in below format

> mon 01/01/1000(TAB)hi hello(TAB)how r you

Is there any way to read the text in such a way to use `'\t'` alone as delimiter (and not space)?

So sample output can be,

> mon 01/01/1000
>
> hi hello
>
> how r you

I couldn't use `fscanf()`, since it reads till the first space only.

Answer (score 14):

Using only standard library facilities:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::ifstream file("file.txt");

std::string line;

std::vector<std::string> tokens;

while(std::getline(file, line)) {     // '\n' is the default delimiter

    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string token;
    while(std::getline(iss, token, '\t'))   // but we can specify a different one
        tokens.push_back(token);
}
```

You can get some more ideas here: [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

from boost :

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
std::vector<std::string> strs;
boost::split(strs, "string to split", boost::is_any_of("\t"));
```

you can specify any delimiter in there.