# C++: String splitting by tabs, but include spaces

Tags: c++, string, sockets, parsing, client-server

I am working on a client/server program using sockets and I am trying to parse the input file. I have a struct to store the Majors, the early career pay, and the mid-career, respectively. The client program asks the user to input the name of the major and the server program returns both salaries.

The issue with the input file is this:

Geophysics  54100   122200

Cognitive Science   54000   121900

Electrical Power Engineering    68600   119100

They are all separated as Major[TAB]Pay[Tab]Pay, and the majors have spaces in them. I want to store each of them in the struct.

**Any solution to this?**

Comment: Hint: `std::getline(input_file, text, '\t')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/the-most-elegant-way-to-iterate-the-words-of-a-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to split a file with space and tab differenciation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617094/how-to-split-a-file-with-space-and-tab-differenciation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with something this:

```
ifstream f("c:\\temp\\test.txt");
string s;
while (getline(f, s))
{
    istringstream iss(s);
    string major, early, mid;
    getline(iss, major, '\t');
    getline(iss, early, '\t');
    getline(iss, mid, '\t');
    cout << major << '|' 
         << early << '|' 
         << mid   << endl;
}
```

Comment: So that prints out everything except the first letter of every major. If I remove the space from the second getline, I get this: Geophysics54100 122200

Comment: This is what I get as output: Major: Petroleum
Early: 
Mid: 
Major: Engineering
Early: 94600
Mid: 
Major: 175500

Comment: But I have to push the data into the struct. I was just using the cout to see if it's being split and stored the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the third argument in `getline()` to say what character to stop at. The default is `\n`, but you can also specify that it is `\t` to have it stop at the tab you want:

```
getline(std::cin, line, '\t');
```